# SharePoint 2013: Saving attachments to DMS

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, dms

We intend to store attachments for a list item on an external Document Management System (DMS). A SOAP web service exists for interacting with the DMS and we've received a WSDL for it.

How can I achieve the scenario where SharePoint is able to talk to the web service and send attachments to store them in the DMS automatically?

Will SharePoint be able to handle this itself or will it involve writing a client in the middle, and if yes, how will the pieces fit in?

Comment: You need custom solution. I would suggest custom url field with WCF service (REST) to get and post file.

Comment: Or maybe I was wrong, check: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/content-management-interoperability-services-cmis-in-sharepoint

Comment: @tinamou thanks, CMIS looks like something I should be looking at. I've never ever done this before. Could you share a concrete example?

Comment: Heard about this today, so unfortunately no./edit I googled: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59189/how-to-activate-and-use-cmis-for-a-sharepoint-2013-server